# Java Read Text File not completely

Tags: java

I write a program to read line by line result from a text file to check for certain condition using below code.

```
for (File f : readAllTxtFile) {
    if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt") && f.getName().length() > 28) {

                Scanner input = new Scanner(f);

                while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                    String lineResult = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println(lineResult); // I print out the line result here

                    if (lineResult.contains("TER_GetCarrierInfo")) {
                       ...//do something
                        break;
                    }
                }
   }
 }
```

My question is, why system only read until half of my txt file and stopped ?? it didnt continue reading the next line eventhough the condition `if (lineResult.contains("TER_GetCarrierInfo"))` is not exist/hit.
My txt file got thousand of line around 900++ kb

Can someone explain with me ?

Thanks and appreaciate

Comment: Basically you are reading multiple file right, So the program stop even on the first file or ?

Comment: Yup, I reading multiple file.. Program run completely, but it just not able to finish read the file. But still able to continue to read another file.
For example:
File ABC got 1000 lines - the system read until line 500 and stop reading the next line, and then continue read another FILE BCD

Comment: How do you identify your program stop at line 500? I have simulate the code and it seem to run as expected.

Comment: Does the error also occur if you remove that `break`? You say *"it is never `true`"* but I'm not sure if you're right. Makes sure it can not be a factor by removing it temporarily.

Comment: Reply to Akjun:
Because I use `system.print` to print out the line result. And then I just identify the last printed line result and compare with my txt file. 500 is just an assumption number.

Comment: Reply to Zabuza:
Yup.. After i removed the `break` , it still remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i use to simulate your scenario.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        File dir = new File("/yourpath");
        File[] readAllTxtFile = dir.listFiles();

        for (File f : readAllTxtFile) {
            if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt") && f.getName().length() > 28) {

                Scanner input = new Scanner(f);

                while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                    String lineResult = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println(lineResult); // I print out the line result here

                    if (lineResult.contains("TER_GetCarrierInfo")) {
                        //do something
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

If you want to check if your program continue to read after 500 line, put 'TER_GetCarrierInfo' in your text file after line 500 and replace the code segment

```
if (lineResult.contains("TER_GetCarrierInfo")) {
   System.out.println("Found 'TER_GetCarrierInfo' ");
   break;
}
```

This will show that your program continue even after half of the file is scan.HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Actually my txt file contains 'TER_GetCarrierInfo' after line 500. Example in line 700 will appear 'TER_GetCarrierInfo' . Because in the line 'TER_GetCarrierInfo' i would like to get the serial Number. But my serial number return null. So after I debug I found out the system read the file and stop in half way.
So weird

Comment: I see, then it might be when you retrieve your serial number the program stop to scan from there and continue to read in another file. If it is not available to show your retrieve method here. I suggest you to look into your retrieve serial number method and find out why it stop scanning the current file.

Comment: Alright.. Thanks for your suggestion.
I try to change to use `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));` and it work fine... hmmmm....

Answer (score 0):

Alright..
I try to change to use

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

and it work fine... hmmmm....